# Edit and Create Features "Pre Utility Network"

Tags: arcgis-pro, utility-network, arcgis-water-utilities

I am creating and editing water utility features. I am learning more about the utility network tools, specifically the ability to trace lines to know which valves to turn off to perform maintenance. We are not able to use the utility network tools, but are considering purchasing the license.

To make the utility network functionality work, should water meter tap lines be one single polyline from the main line to the meter to the house, or should there be two polylines, one from the main to the meter and another from the meter to the house? All polylines would be snapped to edges and ends as necessary.